# How long should I wait for being invited after being accepted in the eligible pool for Canadian PR?

Tags: canada

The Canadian Govt website says that an applicant will remain in the pool for 1 year. What happens after that? Do they inform the applicants about the "invitation to apply for PR" exactly after a year?

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about Express Entry. I think you are misinformed. After you are in the pool, if your score is higher than the cut off score in any of the draws, you get invited to apply for Permanent Residence right away. If your score is lower and you don't get invited and an year passes, your profile is marked as inactive and taken out of the pool.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are talking about Express Entry. I think you are misinformed. After you are in the pool, if your score is higher than the cut off score in any of the draws, you get invited to apply for Permanent Residence right away. If your score is lower and you don't get invited and an year passes, your profile is marked as inactive and taken out of the pool.